# How to modify an extracted node key from an std::map

Tags: c++, c++17

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66407357/3149379), I wanted to store some extracted nodes from an `std::map` into a `std::vector<std::map<K, V>::node_type>`, using a `for` loop. Now that I can do that, I'd like
to modify the nodes keys before storing them in the `vector`, and I'm getting a compilation error (not copying the whole error message, it's very long) :

```cpp
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:514:4: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at'
          std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```cpp
  std::vector<decltype(myMap)::node_type> tmp;
  for (auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end();) {
    if (it->second->needsToBeModified()) {
      auto out = it++;
      auto node = myMap.extract(out);
      node.key() = someNewKey;
      tmp.push_back(node); // The above error message points to this line
    } else
      it++;
  }
```

If I don't put the node into a variable, the error is gone :

```cpp
  std::vector<decltype(myMap)::node_type> tmp;
  for (auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end();) {
    if (it->second->needsToBeModified()) {
      auto out = it++;
      tmp.push_back(myMap.extract(out)); // This is fine
    } else
      it++;
  }
```

So I guess there is something with the way I manipulate the node but I can't figure it out yet. Could it be possible the problem is with my key which is an `std::pair<int16_t, uint32_t>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node handles are not copyable. Thus, you cannot create a copy in the vector.

Node handles are movable though, which is why the other example works.

Moving from a variable can be done using the standard function `std::move`:

```
tmp.push_back(std::move(node))
```

Comment: "node handle", as a thing, was introduced in C++17 and is described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) - along with the explanation, given by eerorika, that it is move only.  Interesting use cases are: transferring a node between containers (with restrictions on what _kind_ of containers), or changing the key of a node.